# conversion of number from base 10 to base 16

Tags: number-theory, binary

I have trouble finding an example of a conversion of a number from base 10 to base 16, where there is a loss of significant digits when using the Euclidean algorithm due to division by large numbers, while there is no such loss when using the Horner algorithm.

Any sort of tip or help is appreciated.
Thank you!